# Is it possible to convert a jar to exe using Ant build in Linux?

Tags: java, packaging

I have created an project and need to distribute it over Windows.  I need to create an exe for it I already know that there is a lot of tools like:

1. JSmooth
2. Launch4J
3. Executor
4. Advanced Installer etc.

The installer windows are done in Java itself.  Means like the selecting locations, licensing etc. the only thing I need is to create an exe that should open this jar.  Is that possible in Linux?

Comment: why not make the jar file executable, and then you just need a .sh file with the correct parameters to launch it, and for windows you just need a .bat file.

Comment: You can't make the jar file executable on Linux and have it work. You can make the shell script executable and have it call the java command to launch the app in the jar.

Answer (score 1):

For a Java app. with a GUI, [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is the best option.  It is supplied and maintained by the maker of the JRE, and therefore works on Windows, *nix **and Mac.**

Answer (score 1):

I do understand the need for an .exe on Windows and I've used JSmooth before.

I would just make a shell script which launches the program. I think a shell script is fine for Linux: icons aren't built into the executable and you can't discover the location of a usable JVM automatically.